# npm run script deletes flags

Tags: npm, terminal

In my package.json in scripts i have this

```
"typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

i want to be able to extend this script from cli usage eg.

```
npm run typeorm migration:create -n Example
```

but when i do run it like that in terminal this gets executed:

```
ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js "migrations:create" "Example"
```

note that the flag -n is being deleted by npm
Do you know how would i run scripts like this and keep flags and everything thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i have found an answer ... just add -- after npm run typeorm

example:

```
npm run typeorm -- migration:create -n Example
```

everyting after -- will be added directly to script according to docs